# Explicit example of non abelian group of order $pq$ where $p \mid q-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

I want to show groups from semi-direct product of order $pq$ where $p \mid q-1$ is non-abelian.

I know $\mathbb{Z}_p \rtimes _\phi \mathbb{Z}_q$ is a group for non-trivial group homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathrm{Aut} (\mathbb{Z}_q)$, and they are all the same. Many texts claim this group is non-abelian, but how do we know it is non-abelian?

Consider $\mathbb{Z}_3 \rtimes _\phi \mathbb{Z}_7$ where $\mathbb{Z}_3=\{0,1,2\}$ defined by $\phi(1_{\mathbb{Z}_3})=2_{\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_7)}$. So $\phi(2)=4$ and $x_{\mathrm{Aut}(Z_7)}(y_{Z_7})=xy_{Z_7}$. I just plugged in random values and found
$$
(3,1)\cdot_\rtimes(4,2)=(3\phi(1)(4),2)=(3\cdot4\cdot2,2)=(3,2) \\
(4,2)\cdot_\rtimes(3,1)=(4\phi(2)(3),2)=(4\cdot3\cdot4,2)=(6,2)
$$

So $\mathbb{Z}_3 \rtimes _\phi \mathbb{Z}_7$ is non abelian. Is there a way to generalize this to show all groups generated by non trivial homomorphism to automorphism is non-abelian? Or am I missing out a more simple elementary argument?

(Note: I’m not exactly sure if my notation is correct, please correct if there’s a mistake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $S_3=\mathbb{Z}_3\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2$ is an easy example of a non-abelian groups of order $pq$. Let $H=\langle a\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $K=\langle b\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$. Then $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ has one non-trivial automorphism $\pi: 1\mapsto 1, a\mapsto a^2, a^2\mapsto a$. Conjugation by $b$ induces this automorphism, so $b^{-1}ab=a^2$ and $b^{-1}a^2b=a$.

---

To answer your question: If we have a semidirect product $G=K\rtimes_{\phi} H$ where $H$ and $K$ are cyclic then $G$ is abelian if and only if the automorphism $\phi$ of $H$ is trivial. To see this, remember that $k^{-1}hk=\phi(h)$ for some generator $k$ of $K$.

1. If $\phi$ is trivial then $\phi(h)=h$ for all $h\in H$. Therefore, $k^{-1}hk=h$ for all $h\in H, k\in K$, and so every element of $H$ commutes with every element of $K$. Hence, $G$ is abelian as required.
2. If $\phi$ is non-trivial then there exists some $h\in H$ such that $\phi(h)\neq h$. Therefore, $k^{-1}hk\neq h$, and so $h$ and $k$ do not commute. Hence, $G$ is not abelian as required.

Comment: Isn’t $\phi:H \to \text{Aut}(K)$? Sorry, I don’t really understand the notation, what is $\phi(h)(k)$ supposed to be? Why must group homomorphisms to automorphism of cyclic group be inner automorphisms? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @VladimirPutin I originally wrote $H\rtimes K$ (in correct alphabetical order!), so wrote it as $\phi: H\rightarrow\mathrm{Aut}(K)$. However, I noticed you had written "$\mathbb{Z}_p \rtimes _\phi \mathbb{Z}_q$ is a group for non-trivial group homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathrm{Aut} (\mathbb{Z}_q)$" so swapped the $H$ and $K$ in my definition to agree with what you had written. Its not a big deal though.

Comment: I didn't write $\phi(h)(k)$ (or if I did I didn't mean to and cannot see it now). For semidirect products we have a map $K\rightarrow\mathrm{Aut}(H)$, and then (1) $K$ acts by conjugation on $H$, and (2) this action corresponds to the above map. So in $G$ the map is an inner automorphism, but in $H$ it is not. Play around with $S_3$; its small enough.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t knew that group homomorphism to automorphism group must be conjugation action. I was worried it could send something to the outer automorphism group (well, my fault for not reading D&F properly)

Comment: @VladimirPutin Not quite. The image of $\phi$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ can be *anything*. However, when this is embedded into $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ then it is inner. (Remember, cyclic groups have no non-trivial inner automorphisms.) I've expanded my $S_3$ example a bit.